# Dynamic rooms; React Native with SocketIO without NodeJS

Tags: android, ios, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am creating a React Native application where users play a game in pairs. As soon as one user presses the play button on the menu screen, it looks for a room to join. If there are no rooms, it creates one. Would that be possible without NodeJS? Also is this question similar to this post: [Socket.io managing rooms; allow 2 people per room, create new rooms dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977252/socket-io-managing-rooms-allow-2-people-per-room-create-new-rooms-dynamically)

Comment: There needs to be a server (nodejs) for the sockets to work. I don't think peer to peer connections are possible with socketIO.You might have look at alternatives for peer to peer connections.

Comment: Could this work?: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-p2p

Comment: or this?: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-multipeer

Comment: At least with browser, this isn't possible.See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118272/do-websockets-allow-for-p2p-browser-to-browser-communication

I'm not sure whether it's possible in react native, as the requests are not initiated/received from browser.

Comment: So its not possible to make an internal server on the mobile devices as well?